# Regular expressions - Unable to match this string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am writing a ruby script requiring pattern matching. I got most however I am unable to match a long string of `01122223_200000_1717181` so on using
`/ (\d+\_+\d+)*/`.

It's matching with the following pattern though `/ \**|TYPE:|\=*/`. I can't figure out why. I have checked the ordering of the pattern matching too.

Does someone have any suggestion?

Comment: You have some code you can show us?

Comment: Can you give us some clearer guidelines of what your input should look like? Maybe some other sample inputs?

Comment: Don’t quantify the whole thing with a `*`: that makes it successfully match nothing, and even at best you would only capture the last of the matches.

Answer (score 3):

You have more than one thing going on with your pattern, but I think only one is causing matching to fail:

- Your parentheses are slightly off.
- You have a `+` after the underscore, but I don't think you want/need one.
- You have an extra whitespace at the beginning of the pattern.

Of these, probably the only issue preventing you from getting a match is the last one. The rest of the pattern should still match, though probably not quite the way you want it to (meaning it'll match some things you wouldn't want it to match). I'd go with this:

```
/\d+(_\d+)+/
```

If you want to accept a pattern with no underscores (e.g. 999999), use this:

```
/\d+(_\d+)*/
```

**About your second question:** The reason it's matching `/ \**|TYPE:|\=*/` is that `\**` and `\=*` use `*` as a quantifier, rather than `+`. That means they'll match even if the input contains no `*` or `=` characters at all. `\=*` matches an empty string, so *that expression will match any input.* Change it to `/ \*+|TYPE:|\=+/` and it shouldn't match anymore.

Answer (score 2):

For matching that first string (`01122223_200000_1717181`) this might do the trick: `/(\d+_)+\d+/`

Answer (score 0):

My more-or-less first idea was:

```
/\d+(_\d+)*/
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be easy. Just use ranges.

```
/[\d_]*\d/
```

Comment: This will match `______9`, `9`, and `999`, none of which fit the format.

Comment: @Justin The OP does not say those do not fit the format. The OP only gives one example, and how can you be sure about that?

Comment: It's not so much the `9` or `9999`. I wasn't sure if those were included either, so I don't have a problem with those. It's pretty clear from the example that `_________9` shouldn't be included, however. If you improve your answer I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: What rule do you have in mind? Even if you give me a rule, that's what you give me, and it's not the OPs.

Comment: That was the intent of my first comment: I admit the question is unclear, but it seems clear enough to tell that `_________9` shouldn't be allowed. Did you intend to allow that?

Comment: @Justin. Yes. What is the rule that disallows it?

Comment: Do you honestly think that was intended as an acceptable match? No other answerers share that belief, and even the original `/ (\d+\_+\d+)*/` pattern--though mistaken--gives enough information to see that that was almost certainly not the original intent.

Comment: I don't want to argue the point, and I don't like downvoting anyway. If you improve your answer, or the asker posts something that suggests it's acceptable, I'll remove the -1. I made it because I thought the answer was flawed, to the point of being harmful. Meanwhile, if you feel that way about *my answer*, say so and I'll do whatever I can to improve it. If you downvote a *person*, you're missing the point.

Comment: @Justin I don't understand what you mean my improving my answer. If the OP shows additional examples and my interpretation of the question changes, I might change my answer, but at this point, I don't see any flaws with it. In the second bullet of your answer, you are adding your own assumptions, going against the original regex.